# Is it true that $ Av=\lambda v \implies v^{*T}Av = \lambda?$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

Is this generally true? I worked it out on paper and it seems to be the case but I'm not sure if I did everything correctly?

Comment: Is what generally true? What is $v$, what is $v^T v$?

Comment: $v$ is the eigenvector corresponding the the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $v^{*T}$ is its conjugate transpose.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer my other question. Basically I'm asking what makes you think $v^{*T} v = 1$?

Comment: I don't understand the question: right now, I see "$v^{*T}Av = \lambda$ such that $Av = \lambda v$" which I don't know how to interpret as a statement

Comment: @Gregory, it came out of a question I was working on. So maybe it's not 1, but it is some constant equal to a*a+b*b. In my problem it is one because of a normalisation such that a^2 + b^2 = 1

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am asking if multiplying a diagonalisable matrix by the conjugate transpose of one of it's eigenvectors and again by the same eigenvector will return the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: The condition to work this out is straightforward enough.
\begin{align}
Av & = \lambda v \\
v^H A v & = \lambda v^H v
\end{align}
If $v^H V = 1$ you have your result. But no, its not ``generally" true, as you require a special condition that $v^H v = 1$.

Comment: Okay, so you mean "does $Av = \lambda v$ imply that $v^{*T}Av = \lambda$".

Comment: @Gregory, thanks, I forgot to mention the normalisation, it makes sense now

Comment: No problem, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this was addressed in the comments, but here's the answer for the sake of having an answer:

I use $v^*$ instead of $v^{*T}$. Note that if $Av = \lambda v$ and $\|v\| = 1$, we have
$$
v^*Av = v^*(\lambda v) = \lambda(v^*v) = \lambda \|v\|^2
$$
so, if $v$ is a *unit* eigenvector, $v^*Av = \lambda$ holds.